# Windsor Optional Constructor Parameters

Tags: .net, dependency-injection, castle-windsor

How can I have Windsor respect optional constructor parameters for injection?

I tried making an IContributeComponentModelConstruction that loops through each ParameterInfo of each constructor and checks if it IsOptional, then sets IsOptional on the Windsor Dependency object accordingly, but this doesn't seem to do the trick. I still get a "Could not instantiate because of dependency...etc.".

Thanks.

UPDATE:

I'm using 2.5.2.0 for Silverlight 4.0 and can reproduce with the following:

```
    var container = new WindsorContainer();
    container.Register(Component.For<TestClass>());
    container.Resolve<TestClass>(); //boom

    public class TestClass
    {
        public TestClass(ITest test=null)
        {

        }
    }

    public interface ITest
    {

    }


Missing dependency.
Component TestClass has a dependency on ITest, which could not be resolved.
Make sure the dependency is correctly registered in the container as a service, or provided as inline argument.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It does in v2.5.2.

**update**
I had a look and ran the code you pasted and you're right it's not working. Windsor does correctly recognise that the parameter has a default value. However Windsor has also a second rule, that `null` is never a valid value for a required dependency, and this second rule wins in your case.

This should probably be considered a bug.

To make it work you will need to replace the `DefaultDependencyResolver` with your own.

You'll need to override two methods: from `DefaultDependencyResolver` pretty much like this:

```
public class AllowDefaultNullResolver : DefaultDependencyResolver
{
    protected override bool CanResolveServiceDependency(CreationContext context, ComponentModel model, DependencyModel dependency)
    {
        return base.CanResolveServiceDependency(context, model, dependency) || dependency.HasDefaultValue;
    }

    protected override object ResolveServiceDependency(CreationContext context, ComponentModel model, DependencyModel dependency)
    {
        try
        {
            return base.ResolveServiceDependency(context, model, dependency);
        }
        catch (DependencyResolverException)
        {
            if(dependency.HasDefaultValue)
            {
                return dependency.DefaultValue;
            }
            throw;
        }
    }
}
```

and use this resolver instead of the default one.

Comment: Thanks! It does without a custom contributor, automatically? Or do I still need the custom contributor?

Comment: Still can't get it working, please see updated description. Thanks.

Comment: What exactly is "replace the DefaultDependencyResolver with your own"?
I have instantiated container as ```new WindsorContainer(new DefaultKernel(new AllowDefaultNullResolver(), new DefaultProxyFactory), new DefaultCompnentInstaller())``` and still getting DependencyResolverException when passing null values because HasDefaultValue returns false for them.
In general this answer is incomplete and misleading.